# how to simulate onBlur in React Native

Tags: react-native

we want to use our custom keyBoad because we can't prevent the system keyBoad to show,so we use a View to simulate Input,but i can't find a way to simulate onBlur,do anyone has some method

Comment: Textinput has event. `onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
                  this.refs.inputContactNo.focus();
                } }`
I am not getting you complete. Let me know what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: we use the View to simulate TextInput because we need to use our customized keyboard，but i have no idea how to simulate onblur

Comment: take View
`<View ref='modal'>
    <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput .... />
          <TextInput .... />
    </View>
</View>`

and code 

`this.refs.modal.blur();`